# download git repository from 923daf ... to 4292ab

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to download from the repository that I have but only the changed files only, for example yesterday I commit to hash 923daf and today I commit to hash 4292ab, and I just want to download from 923daf until 4292ab only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, but there is a way to do it

1. Download/Clone the repository
2. do git archive command `git archive -o ./commit_files.zip 4292ab $(git diff --name-only 923daf --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB)`
3. voila you get zip files contains only files in commit 4292ab to 923daf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extract a specific set of files from a remote with `git` alone.

As HBHB said in the comments, you can use shallow cloning (`--depth`), to limit the amount number of commits in your clone, but only so long as that latest commit (in your case 4292ab) is a branch tip, in which case you also need `--branch <your branch's name>`. But even in this case, you're still downloading all of the files at that branch tip; shallow cloning only limits the history, and not the actual files that end up in your working directory.

There may be third-party git hosting services that provide an API for this sort of thing, though I don't believe BitBucket is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You must obtain the full copy of the repository. This is the well known "feature" of git.

Afterwords you can for instance rebase using only commits you need.